# Как передать 2 id из div'a в js?

Tags: javascript, html, vkontakte-api

Есть два кода js:

— один выводит до 1000 элементов (содержащие aid и owner_id):

```
function recommendate(){
    VK.Api.call('audio.getRecommendations', {count: '1000'}, function(r) {
      if(r.response) {
        $('#playlist').empty().append($.map(r.response, function(song){
          return '<li><a href="'+ song.url +'"><b>'+song.artist+'</b> - '+ song.title +'</a><div class="add-song" data-aid="'+ song.aid +'" data-aid-id="'+ song.owner_id +'"></div><a href="javascript:addaudio();">+</a></li>'
        }))
      }
    });
};
```

— второй нужно передать параметры и выполнить код

```
function addaudio() {
    VK.Api.call('audio.add', 
                { audio_id: Сюда song.aid , owner_id: Сюда song.owner_id }, 
                function (data) {
                    if (data.response) {
                        console.log(data.response);
                    }
                });
};
```

Вопрос: как мне при нажатии на + передать это все в js и выполнить запрос?
Собственно нужно взять song.aid и song.owner_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно добавить дополнительные атрибуты в `<a href="javascript:addaudio();">+</a>`

```js
function recommendate(){
VK.Api.call('audio.getRecommendations', {count: '1000'}, function(r) {
  if(r.response) {
    $('#playlist').empty().append($.map(r.response, function(song){
      return '<li><a href="'+ song.url +'"><b>'+song.artist+
      '</b> - '+ song.title +'</a><div class="add-song" data-aid="'+ 
      song.aid +'" data-aid-id="'+ song.owner_id +
      '"></div><a data-audio-id="'+song.aid+'" data-owndr_id="'+
      song.owner_id+'" href="javascript:addaudio();">+</a></li>'
    }))
  }
});
```

И обращаться к этим атрибутам по клику

**Обновление**

Я бы лучше удалил `href="javascript:addaudio();"`, потому что я даже не знаю как в таком случае передать контекст вызова :) Лучше воспользуйтесь привычным добавлением слушателя на клик, например - [моё решение](https://jsfiddle.net/vvLve53a/1/). P.S. Добавление слушателя нужно реализовать после выполнения функции recommendate, иначе скрипт просто не найдет плюсики.

Comment: а во второй код как передать эти атрибуты?

Comment: <a data-audio-id="264255333" data-owndr_id="22260495">+</a> вот так щас в браузере выглядит строка соответственно при нажатии на + ничего не произойдет я в js не оч силен,помоги плиз а если можешь то и еще подробнее объясни))